# Jquery takes my badly formed html and "fixes". How do I stop this

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ladies and gents of the internet I have an issue with jquery.

I have 3 templates on a page one for the top of a table one for the bottom and one for the rows. They look like this.

Header

```
<div class="col-md-12 tableContainer">
    <table class="table table-hover table-condensed">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="hidden-xs"></th>
                <th></th>
                <th>Artist</th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
```

Row

```
<tr data-bind='{"visible":"!isFiltered"}' class="handPointer">
    <td style="width: 22px;">
        <img alt="{{Libary}}" src="#:libaryImageSrc#" width="22"/>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 22px;">
        <span 
              class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" 
              aria-hidden="true" 
              data-bind='{"click":"spawnAddToPlaylistModal"}'>
        </span>
    </td>
    <td><span>{{Name}}</span></td>
    <td><span data-bind='{"click":"loadAlbums"}'>Albums</span></td>
    <td><span data-bind='{"click":"loadSongs"}'>Songs</span></td>
</tr>
```

Footer

```
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The issue is that when I try and use my templates as html objects jquery assumes I have just been lasy and left of the closing tag and breaks every thing. I have a function that parses and creates the templates in batches so the execution of the rendering of 1000s of lines does not lock up the user interface. I also have a widget binding engine I made so I can bind functions using data-bind on the html elements.

The catch is I want them to render all at the same time not section at a time so I create document fragments and then once all the batch is completed I Inject the pre-bound html like so. This is in a function that first calls the headers then x rows then the footer.

```
// Bootstrap render call function 
// Results in correct markup as a string
template = bootstrapTemplateObject(dataSource[0]);

// At this point I need a htmlObject so I call it in jquery
// but then jquery decides it can fix it
htmlObject = $(template);
// Then I add the fragment
fragment.appendChild(htmlObject[0]);
// Then I bind the fragment
widget.bind(htmlObject, 0);
```

Question is can I stop jquery "fixing" my code. If so how?

----- **Update 1** -----

Ok so following on from PJs answer I have created the following.

```
// First empty the target
target.empty();

// As Paul-Jan suggested we create one big string of html so it is well formed(or at least should be).
template = "";

// If we have a header we add it
if (header !== null) {
    template += header(dataSource[0]);
}

// Then we start the hackyness by adding a target placeholder for later. 
// I choose script as far as im aware this can go anywhere with out being incorrect html.
// And at this point I dont know if the header / footer are acting as a container ie nested or not.
template += "<script id='superMergerTarget'></script>";

// If we have footer add it.
if (footer !== null) {
    template += footer(dataSource[0]);
}

// Now we make the string a html object
htmlObject = $(template);

// So at this point we could have nothing but the script or a container or a wrapper
// So we iterate over like so.
for (var k = 0; k < htmlObject.length; k++)
{
    var targetReplaceo = $(htmlObject[k]).
        // check if its nested in container situation.
        find('#superMergerTarget').
        // Check self if wrapper or single situation.
        addBack('#superMergerTarget');

    if (targetReplaceo.length === 1) {
        var element = targetReplaceo[0];
        if (element.parentElement === null)
        {
            // If we are in here then either the header and or footer dont exists.
            // Or the header and footer are stand alone html not wrapping the content.
            // So we just go ahead and chuck it in the target.
            if (header !== null) {
                template = header(dataSource[0]);
                htmlObject = $(template);
                widget.bind(htmlObject, 0);
                target.append(htmlObject);
            }
            target[0].appendChild(fragment);
            if (footer !== null) {
                template = footer(dataSource[0]);
                htmlObject = $(template);
                widget.bind(htmlObject, 0);
                target.append(htmlObject);
            }

            break;
        }

        widget.bind(htmlObject, 0);

        // This part seems filthy and there is probably a much better way of doing it.
        // First we get an element to add the fragment too.
        var newElement = element.cloneNode();
        newElement.innerHTML = "";
        newElement.appendChild(fragment);
        // then we get the individual templates and add them one at a time.
        var childNodes = newElement.childNodes;

        for (var l = 0; l < childNodes.length; l++)
        {
            element.parentNode.insertBefore(childNodes[l], element);
        }

        // then remove the placeholder
        element.parentNode.removeChild(element);

        // then we add it to the target.
        target.append(htmlObject);

        break;
    }
}
```

I feel like it could be much better but it does work so I'm happy with that, can anyone suggest a better way?

Comment: if you do not want jquery to do html shenanigans, you will need to append your html as un-escaped text somehow. that means you won't be using any `appendChild` or anything else DOM-related functions to append whatever you want to.

Comment: Unfortunately i need it to be a html object so that i can call fragment.appendChild see here for a bit of info https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment

Comment: I wonder if there is a better way of adding the fragment. That doesn't fix the broken html. Or perhaps the best way is to render the footer and header together with a place holder element in the middle then inject into it. but I really would like to not add and extra render event.

Comment: you can't use fragments for building this, you need to build it into one string before turning it into anything DOM-related, fragments or elements. strings would be faster than fragments anyway, but the real issue is that there's no way to build half a tree in a DOM.

Comment: Using the fragments works quite well for me currently provided that the templates used are correctly formed html. I.e not nested like the example i provided.

Comment: you can use the fragments to store and append, but you can't have invalid html in a fragment. Tables are where i always have to use `<script type=template>` instead of `<template>` because of the same self-healing aspect as non-live fragments or any DOM tree. it's html, not jQ...

Comment: Can your header/footer not include your container code? basically leave the container code on the page and then just load the fragments as needed

Comment: @Johan Nah because I change the header on footer going from a table to a grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. DocumentFragments are DOM nodes, as such they cannot be constructed from "badly formed HTML". That's hardly jQuery's fault :)

However, I don't see (yet) why you *need* to construct your document fragments from malformed HTML. For instance, what is stopping you from initializing the fragment from the *header **and** the footer* (together they make a valid DOM node), then getting the *tbody* from the fragment, and batchwise attach your rows to it?

Comment: Didnt know you could target child elements of a fragment. Thats a good idea ill have a try see if that works.

Comment: I have attempted to create a solution using your suggestion of combining the header and footer. Is this along the lines of what you where talking about :)?